# How to display only the selected row after clicking edit button?

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

Below is the code on my edit page. I want it to show only the data that I have clicked the edit button on. I click on one row only but then it shows all of the data. Can anyone see what's wrong with the code? I guess there must be some condition on the query, right? But then it shows all of the data.

```
<cfquery name="UpdateCity" datasource="test">                          
  Select name, countrycode, population
  from city
</cfquery>
```

This is the other page after I click the edit button:

[image]

Comment: you have to add code also not only result or error in question see this  link
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are correct - your query needs a condition to limit the data results. You need to pass some index value when you click the row so the query only returns that one row's data.

Comment: In addition to a filter, you probably want to select the primary key field of your table.  City/country combinations are not necessarily unique.  Also, it's rare, but cities do get renamed.  Finally, you may need to give users the opportunity to correct spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Miguel-F so what the condition do i need to put in the query in order to display only selected row after i click the edit button?

Comment: Well that depends on your data. The best/fastest option is to use the primary key field from your table for each row as Dan mentioned.